# Highcharts cloud Scatter plot with data array

Tags: graph, highcharts, scatter-plot, scatter

i would like to plot a scatter plot between 2 time series by using highcharts cloud.
I also would like to visualize in the tooltip the data (like 24/03/2017) in order to see at each point not only the value of the 2 time series, but also the data of the time series.
Someone could help me please?

Daniele

Comment: Can you share the link to Highcharts cloud with your current configuration?

Comment: sorry, which kind of configuration? thanks @morganfree

Answer (score 0):

Just paste your data in format below:

```
Date,stock A,stock B
2021/1/01,10,15
2021/2/01,12,10
```

Examples:

https://jsfiddle.net/kb2ary7y/

http://cloud.highcharts.com/show/aguvama

For scatter:
https://jsfiddle.net/7kzhdtn6/

Comment: this kind of example give me a line plot not a scatter :( thanks very much!

Comment: Just set chart.type to `'scatter'`

Comment: if i select the 'scatter' it gives me "something went wrong creating your chart"...only with line charts it seemes working